# Org-mode `org-mobile-push` and `org-mobile-pull` missing?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to use emacs org-mode with the MobileOrg iphone app. However, I can not use `M-x org-mobile-push` (or `pull`).

I am using emacs-snapshot 23.

How can I enable this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on your version of org-mode. Try these steps to fix the problem:

1. Try adding the following to your init file:

   ```
   (require 'org-install) 
   (require 'org-mobile)
   ```

   Make sure org-mode is in your load path.
2. If that doesn't fix it, enter `M-x org-version RET` while in emacs. If it reports a version less than 7.4 (the current version as of this writing), follow the [upgrade instructions](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#updating-org) to use the latest org-mode code.